# JQuery Template - Getting Index of a JSONList

Tags: jquery, json, jquery-templates

Hi i have a jsonlist object and i send it to a template. and i want to send index of item to getSurname method to get the item from json object. So how can i get index of item of jsonList?

My template :

```
$.template('deneme',
 '<div>${name}: <input onClick='getSurname(\"${$index}\")' 
  type='checkbox' /></div>
```

My Json List:

```
[{"name":"Sedat","surname":"Basar"},
{"name":"Deneme","surname":"Avile"},
{"name":"Ganmaz","surname":"Oyilmna"}]

function getSurname(){
....???
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two thoughts on this one:

1- rather than let the template run on each item of your array, you can pass the entire array to a template and get better access to the index/item information.

```
var data = [{"name":"Sedat","surname":"Basar"},
{"name":"Deneme","surname":"Avile"},
{"name":"Ganmaz","surname":"Oyilmna"}];

$("#deneme").tmpl({ people: data }).appendTo("#content");

<script id="deneme" type="text/html">
    {{each(i, person) people}}
    <div>
        ${name}: <input onClick='getSurname("${i}")' type='checkbox' />
    </div>
    {{/each}}
    <hr />
</script>
```

2- Another alternative is to use the template plugin's [tmplItem](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.tmplitem/) functionality.  This would look something like:

```
var data = [{"name":"Sedat","surname":"Basar"},
{"name":"Deneme","surname":"Avile"},
{"name":"Ganmaz","surname":"Oyilmna"}];

function getSurname(element){
    var data = $(element).tmplItem().data;
    alert(data.surname);
}


$("#deneme").tmpl(data).appendTo("#content");

<script id="deneme" type="text/html">
    <div>
        ${name}: <input onClick='getSurname(this)' type='checkbox' />
    </div>
</script>
```

Samples here: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/XCThu/